# Wordpress WP_Query Array Custom search via taxonomies

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, search, array

I'm trying to write a custom search function for my WordPress site. I'm  using WP_Query and multiple arraylists.

Is it possible to order by search after `taxonomy = pa_felg-bredde` ?

Here is my code so far:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 200,

    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',


        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_felg-bredde',
            'field' => 'slug',

          'terms' => array($f1, $f2, $f3, $f4, $f5, $f6, $f7, $f8, $f9, $f10)

        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_diameter',
            'field' => 'slug',

            'terms' => array($ff1, $ff2, $ff3, $ff4, $ff5, $ff6, $ff7, $ff8, $ff9, $ff10)

        )


    )
));

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I have now changed from taxonomis to custom field data on my products. Stil cant get the search result to be ordered when output to my website.

Anyone got a clue why that is?

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'orderby' => 'cf_felgbredde',
'order' => 'DESC',
'relation' => 'AND',
'meta_query' => array(
array(<br>
'key' => ("cf_felgbredde"),
'value' => array($ff1, $ff2, $ff3, $ff4, $ff5, $ff6, $ff7, $ff8, $ff9, $ff10)
// 'compare' => 'LIKE'
),
array(
'key' => ("cf_hoyde"),
'value' => array($f1, $f2, $f3, $f4, $f5, $f6, $f7, $f8, $f9, $f10)
// 'compare' => 'LIKE'
), 
array(
'key' => ("cf_dimensjon"),
'value' => array($fff1, $fff2, $fff3, $fff4, $fff5, $fff6, $fff7, $fff8, $fff9, $fff10)
// 'compare' => 'LIKE'
),

)
));
```

Comment: If you want to order by a taxonomy value then you probably have a minor flaw in your design imo. Maybe pa_felg-bredde should have been set as a post_meta-field?

Comment: This is a search for certain car wheels. pa_felg-bredde is a attribute on the product that contains wheel width (example: 15,16,16,17)

So its not possible to create a custom search on a product attribute and the order by the size?

Comment: yes it is, if you set the size as a custom field, not so easy if you set it as a taxonomy term.

Comment: Okey, thanks for the tip.
Im now re-importing all the products with product attributes as custom fields.

Should it then be easy to use the ordreby in arrays to order the output?

Comment: Please reformat and properly indent your code. It is a mess and unreadable.